# getting 'Unresolved reference: KeyboardOptions' and 'Unresolved reference: SpanStyle' error in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEPkr.png)

I'm trying to code an app with the little knowledge I have in Android Studio. And I've encountered two errors, one says 'Unresolved reference: KeyboardOptions.' the other one says 'Unresolved reference: SpanStyle' How can I fix this? I don't know how to fix it by myself. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For first you dont usign SpanSpace so delete this record from importing, and do this always if you dont import and have error with importing, becouse this mean, that path not exist, so you cant use it, and android studio show you this like in this situation, and next, you chosen wrong path to KeyboardOptions, use this one  `import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions`, so switch the path to this which I send you right now.